# Where can one get one's philosophy paper edited?

Tags: publications

I have some philosophy works that I want to see improved into a more succinct, scholarly text. Where can I get such help (for free if possible)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. This one is better suited for http://academia.stackexchange.com. Could the mods migrate this one?

Comment: What is your work about?

Comment: If they are relatively short (less than 10 pages) and on  topics of interest to me, I'll read them and offer what criticism I can. :)

Comment: Update: The Academia mods don't want this question, but they referred me to this one currently on their site: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9939/how-to-hire-editor-to-improve-my-paper

Comment: There are often writing centers at universities; and just in passing, if you actually like writing philosophy papers, you might consider taking a graduate degree ;)

Answer (score 2):

Nobody who has the skillset to do what you want is going to do it for free. Professional philosophers and advanced grad students are pretty busy people. Would you ask a medical doctor to help you with your medical article for free? Would you ask a lawyer to help you with your law review article for free?

Comment: I thought there might have been a website for this...

Comment: Or to put shane's answer another way, there may be people who will read your paper for free, but they are probably not going to be helpful. Anyone capable of moving a paper forward and who isn't your spouse, brother, or uncle, doesn't have the time/interest to revise random papers for the fun of it.

Comment: Well, aside from the whole journal refereeing self-exploitation business aka "service to the community" :)

Comment: @DBK -- journals don't do that level of editing for you, and they tend to reject things that are quite poor after a brief reading of the abstract without comment.

Answer (score 1):

semester is about to start; go join a university course asap and ask your tutor if they will help you work on some essay/s that you have already started work on. they won't be obliged to help, but they might be willing to if they think it will help you on your course.