# Where can one "peer discuss" an unpublished short paper?

Tags: publications

Do you know of an online website where one can present an unpublished short paper for some feedback?

I am interested in a discussion of the ideas themselves, **not** in help editing it into academic form as was requested here: [Where can one get one's philosophy paper edited?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15307/where-can-one-get-ones-philosophy-paper-edited)

If I understand correctly philosophy-SE is not intended for that, and I have not found another place with a good signal to noise ratio.

Comment: You could ask in the stackexchange for academia per se http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If anyone around SE knows of a good place to discuss philosophy online, they are are probably members of philosophy SE.

Comment: I have heard of  virtual discussion groups for dissertation writers in philosophy, but if you are not a student in a university I don't know where you should turn for free of charge feedback. Of course nothing prevents you from asking someone. http://forums.philosophyforums.com/ is a quite active discussion site.

Comment: This point is unclear; are you looking for a publisher or promoter? there are sites like http://philpapers.org/ but they are more of a promoter of papers/articles that are published in journals or on college websites.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [academia.edu](http://www.academia.edu)  It's also a great resource for reading interesting unpublished papers.

Comment: That's not really a good place to get feedback per se especially if you're an unknown person, there are few people interested in giving random comments on academia.edu.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your situation. If you are a member of an academic institution at whatever level, you can approach a senior either to read the paper or to advise you on how to proceed. You might also organise a discussion group or offer to read your work at a seminar.

If you submit the paper for publication, you may well get Reader's comments which would point out weak or disputable points.

If there are particular ideas or arguments that you feel uncertain about, you could put questions on this site. With moderate care you should be able to put questions that don't give away whatever is original in the paper.

Just suggestions.